# Hyperledger explorer is unable to connect to the network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have my network up and running. When I try to connect the same with the latest explorer it throws the following error.

config.json: looks like:

```js
{
"network-configs": {
  "network-1": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "clients": {
      "client-1": {
        "tlsEnable": false,
        "organization": "Org1MSP",
        "channel": "mychannel",
        "credentialStore": {
          "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
          "cryptoStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "channels": {
      "mychannel": {
        "peers": {
          "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
        },
        "connection": {
          "timeout": {
            "peer": {
              "endorser": "6000",
              "eventHub": "6000",
              "eventReg": "6000"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "organizations": {
      "Org1MSP": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "fullpath": false,
        "adminPrivateKey": {
          "path": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
        },
        "signedCert": {
          "path": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
      },
      "Org2MSP": {
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "adminPrivateKey": {
          "path": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore"
        }
      },
      "OrdererMSP": {
        "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
        "adminPrivateKey": {
          "path": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
        }
      }
    },
    "peers": {
      "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "tlsCACerts": {
          "path": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053",
        "grpcOptions": {
          "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        }
      },
      "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:8051"
      },
      "peer0.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:9051"
      },
      "peer1.org2.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:10051"
      }
    },
    "orderers": {
      "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
      }
    }
  },
  "network-2": {}
},
"configtxgenToolPath": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/bin",
"license": "Apache-2.0"
  }
```

I am not sure what is the 'client-1' should be give. When I run the **./start.sh** inside the blockchain-explorer root. I am getting this logs.

```js
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
(node:13053) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
2019-04-01T10:17:57.685Z - ESC[31merrorESC[39m: [Channel.js]: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error: Failed to discover ::Error: 2 UNKNOWN: Stream removed
    at Channel._initialize (/home/karthikeyan/repo/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:347:11)
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections
```

No idea why the stream is removed.